# how do I skip a middle node?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to write code for a Linked List so that it deletes a node in the linked list, it can be any node except for the first and last nodes in the linked list. I have come up with some ideas below.

I'm not sure how to complete it, I know there needs to be some reference to k in the while loop, so that we skip over the node when traversing the linked list, but how can I reference this k? Would I do a 'for I in range k', and then on the kth iteration perform the skip?

```
 def delete_middle(l1,k):

    if l1.head is None:
        return None

    current = l1.head
    while current:
        if current == k:
            current.next = current.next.next

        current = current.next

    return head



    node.value = node.next.value
    node.next = node.next.next
```

Comment: You can use conditional expression which will detect node which you need to skip.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a problem with that, but how would I embed this conditional expression into my code? This is a difficulty I have.

Comment: It may help to draw a picture!

Comment: @Kwanchong, I'm kinda disappointed with your question. To embed expression in your code you can put it under you *for* loop which will let program check it on each iteration.

Comment: let me edit the question/ code. Is the above correct? And is it right to say that we no longer need the final two lines of code? Since we are skipping the node altogether? (I have left it out of the function on purpose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the kth node where k is an integer you can do this:

```
 def delete_middle(l1,k):
    if (l1.head is None) or (k == 0) or (k == find_length(l1) - 1): # second condition checks if k is the first value and the third condition checks if k is the last value which you didn't want to remove.
        return None
    n = 0 # index counter for the values in the linked list
    head = l1.head
    current = head
    while current is not None:
        if n + 1 == k: # check if the next node is the node that you want to remove
            current.next = current.next.next
            break
        current = current.next
        n += 1
    return head

def find_length(l1): # to returns the length of the linked list
    curr = l1.head
    n = 0
    while curr is not None:
        curr = curr.next
        n += 1
    return n
```

Also, I'd recommend defining a linked list class with methods like these inside so you won't have to care about returning any value while updating the linked list unless an invalid value is sent.

Comment: Your code is so clean! I totally understand it. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help